# Save traffic source data

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics, analytics

With the old version of Google Analytics it was possible to extract information about users acquisition channels using the source, medium, term, content, campaign, and gclid parameters that were stored in the __utmz cookie.

This is not possible with the new version of Google Analytics, that uses only the _ga cookie and store the previously mentioned data only server side.

Is there a way to retrieve the same data? For exaple for the source I could use the referer header, right? What about the other parameters?

Do you know if this is possible maybe using any other analytics platform (e.g. Clicky or Piwik)?

Comment: Hi marcosh, I have deleted my answer since it seems I was wrong. Looks   like there really is no way to get at the data (except to parse the referrer which will at least get you a rough breakdown of direct/campaign/organic).

Comment: @EikePierstorff thaks anyway for your time!

Comment: I've got the same question. It appears to have been possible with Google Analytics (`ga.js`) but not Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`). The best solution I've been able to come up with is implementing something server-side to do traffic detection - or alternatively something like this: https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative/